# How to send targeted push notifications to a specific client?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, push-notification

I just got started with Java Web Application Development and I've been developing a Web Application with Java Servelts using Apache Tomcat where customers can book appointments with hair stylists. Now I want to add a feature where stylists are notified by a push notification in real time once a client makes an appointment. I did my research and I found out the following ways:

1. Long Polling
2. Server Sent Events/ Event Source
3. Web Sockets

Since the necessary communication is asynchronous from the server, I feel that the Server Sent Events would be the right choice.

I came up with an idea where the book event generates a notification which is stored in a separate table. A thread monitors the data source for any new notifications and notifies the targeted receiver once a new nofication is found.

The issue I am facing here is how to identify the necessary active client out of several clients and target the data to it.

I've been looking everywhere in the internet and I couldn't find any Java Servlet and Tomcat implementations for reference.

Is it possible to implement my idea using just Servlets in a Tomcat container?
If there is a better approach to this problem, please let me know.